# Is there a straight forward way to exchange columns in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I wonder whether there is a straight forward way to exchange any pair of columns of a `matrix` in `R`.

Say we want to exchange the first (`i=1`) and third (`j=3`) column in matrix

```
n=3
mat  <- matrix(1:(n^2),ncol=n)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

The following always works, regardless of the size `n` of the matrix

```
i=1; j=3
mat2     <- mat[,i]
mat[,i]  <- mat[,j]
mat[,j]  <- mat2
```

whereas direct commands like `cbind(mat[,3],mat[,2],mat[,1])` (suggested in earlier threads [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724419/is-it-possible-to-swap-columns-around-in-a-data-frame-using-r) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)) are limited to a given `n`.

is there a more direct ways to exchange two columns `i` and `j` in a matrix of size `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column pivoting can be done with pivoting index. Suppose you have matrix `mat` with `n` columns, and you want to pivot columns `i` and `j`, you can do:

```
piv <- 1:n; piv[c(i,j)] <- as.integer(c(j,i))
mat <- mat[, piv]
```

The `as.integer` call is for memory efficiency. `piv <- 1:n` is an integer vector, if `i` and `j` are doubles, simply calling `piv[c(i,j)] <- c(j,i)` will cause `piv` be first copied into a vector of doubles then be updated.

Comment: About the same code length but does not create second, potentially large matrix

Comment: This *will* create a copy of the whole matrix. `mat[, c(i, j)] <- mat[, c(j, i)]` could be better maybe. Also, not sure what you need `as.integer` on a 2 length vector

Comment: Eitherway it will copy the whole thing. The only way I could think of avoid copies it work with a data.table, something like `library(data.table) ;  mat <- as.data.table(matrix(1:(n^2),ncol=n)) ; setcolorder(mat, piv)` which maybe doesn't suit OPs needs

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think you might be able to (at least partially) avoid the copy by using a sparse matrix.